# `save_count` parameter animation matplotlib``

Tags: python, animation, matplotlib

I was looking at the documentation of `matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation`

at http://matplotlib.org/api/animation_api.html .

What does `save_count` do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to find this info is to use `IPython`. For example I executed the following in my session:

```
In [7]: from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation
In [8]: FuncAnimation??
```

This brought up the function documentation, which is more detailed then what is posted on the web api.

```
    # Amount of framedata to keep around for saving movies. This is only
    # used if we don't know how many frames there will be: in the case
    # of no generator or in the case of a callable.
    self.save_count = save_count
```

This is a nice way to go about finding documentation in general. I hope this helps!

Comment: Nice way. Thanks @skywalker

Comment: Or in a python shell `help(FuncAnimation)`

Answer (score 1):

This is explained in the [matplotlib source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/animation.py#L1097) but not in the documentation:

> Amount of framedata to keep around for saving movies. This is only
>   used if we don't know how many frames there will be: in the case of no
>   generator or in the case of a callable.